# Combinations of paths through array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, grid, combinations

How do I solve this: I have an table of letters which is labeled out by each grid point.

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)    o   l   n   c   
(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)    e   t   e   a   
(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)    i   b   t   a   
(3,0)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)    o   m   m   f
```

I am trying to find all possible combinations going through the grid creating lines of 3,4,5 length.

```
   ie: PossibleSolutions = [[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)],[(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)],[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]]
   each of these representing:[[o,l,n],[o,t,t],[o,e,i]]
```

All possible combinations but keeping within the grid layout.

```
from itertools import combinations

def PossibleWords(possible, board):
    words = []

    for i in range(len(possible)):
       words.append(board[possible[i]])

    return words

def Combinations(board):

    coord = list(board.keys())

    temp = []

    temp.append(list(combinations([
                                (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),
                                (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
                                (2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),
                                (3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)
                                                        ], 3)))

   possible = temp[0]

   form = []
   temp = []
   solutions = []

   for i in range(len(possible)):
       form.append(PossibleWords(possible[i], board))

   for i in range(len(form)):
       temp.append(form[i])

   for i in range(len(temp)):
       solutions.append(''.join(temp[i]))

   return solutions






  output = ['ole', 'ole', 'one', 'one', 'oaf', 'oaf', 'let', 'lee', 'lei', 'let', 'lei', 'let', 'lab', 'lam', 'lam', 'lit', 'lam', 'lam', 'net', 'nee', 'net', 'net', 'nam', 'nam', 'nam', 'nam', 'cee', 'cab', 'cat', 'cam', 'cam', 'cam', 'cam', 'eta', 'eta', 'eat', 'eta', 'tea', 'tet', 'tea', 'tab', 'tat', 'tit', 'tom', 'tom', 'eat', 'eta', 'aim', 'aim', 'bam', 'bam', 'tom', 'tom']
```

I've tried combinations() but since my grid is in a list it doesn't follow the grid boundaries. Any guidance would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: What is the output you get and what do you mean "it doesn't follow the grid boundaries" ?

Comment: I add my output at the end of my code. What I mean is combinations in python generates different orders of the table because it is a list. ie: combinations(table,3) generates: [['o','l','n'],['o','l','c'] ...] ; it ignores the order of the grid, and generates none touching letter combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinations of paths through grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309497/combinations-of-paths-through-grid)

Comment: That’s also mine; and no, not yet. Does my question not make sense?

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to post the exact same question (albeit an edited one). I suspect you were merely having trouble editing the previous post. To do that, simply click the edit link right below the tags.

Comment: You’re right, I was having issues editing the code after I posted. Thank you.

Comment: Kudos @jameswendle... Nice job cleaning up. Some of the features for Q&A on stackoverflow can be a bit obscure. I did not even see a "How to edit" on the help page so I couldn't point you there originally. Anywho, the community here is pretty helpful and simply asking via the comments will generally get you favorable results.